# Null and Confidence Intervals

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

[image]

I'm at a loss as how to proceed on this problem.  If I conclude true, don't I want the $43/80$ to be IN the CI.  Since this is saying the conclusion was NOT true, wouldn't I want the percentage to be outside the CI?

Need some guidance here.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see 
[here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the `[self-study]` tag & read 
[its wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Have you been able to calculate the confidence interval?

Comment: If Tom's donuts were not preferred over Jane's, what would the proportions be?

Comment: Since the null hypotheses is that people prefer them about the same, and H1 is that Tom's are preferred, I would need a proportion outside of the 95% CI to reject the Null. But, it's not clear to me how I would calculate what ratio I would need.

Comment: After rereading the problem,  I would say the Null hypotheses is Tom's is greater than. 5. Now, we sample and find the sample data is .53, so I need to evaluate if this data is sufficient to reject the Null. Still not sure of the answer

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming this is a self-study question.)

Note that the questions says that conclusion is that the claim is probably not true.

43 out of 80 will be at the centre of the confidence interval (assuming two-sided), so you will want to find statistical support for something other than 43 out of 80.

What null hypothesis would be sensible in this case?

Comment: So, I would think the Null hypothesis, before the sampled data, would be that people prefer Tom's Doughnuts.  Then, after the data, it turns out that 53% DO think that Tom's are better.  So, the question is puzzling to me that he concludes that Tom's are not better.

Comment: This is from a mid-term preparation package.